# Find all winning auctions of a particular bidder

Tags: mysql

We have two tables for storing auctions & its bids info.

**auction** (which stores the auction info)

```
auction_id auction_name
---------- ---------------------
2216 Test Auction
...
```

**auction_bid** (which stores the auction bids)

```
bid_id amount bidder auction_id
------ -------- ------ ------------
8398 50.0000 53 2216
8397 50.0000 32 2216
8396 20.0000 53 2216

...
```

**Note**: The bidder with max bidding amount is declared as winner. In case of tie bids, the last bidder with max tie amount is declared as winner.
For example in above case winner bidder is 53

Now I want to show all the winning auction info on the user dashboard. For example for bidder = 53
I have used the following Query for the purpose:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.*,
  b.bid_id,
  b.amount,
  b.bidder 
FROM
  auction a 
  LEFT JOIN auction_bid b 
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id 
WHERE b.bidder = 53 
  AND b.amount = 
  (SELECT 
    MAX(amount) 
  FROM
    auction_bid tmp 
  WHERE tmp.auction_id = b.auction_id 
  LIMIT 0, 1)
```

This works fine for bidder = 53.
But for bidder = 32, the same auction is also shown as winning auction.

I know the issue is due to tie bids. How to modify above query so that it works for tie bids?
Any help is really appreciated.

Regards

Comment: To prevent this kind of problem you can use a double primary key, on bid_id & amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the bid_id as your filter both for efficiency sake as well as making sure only one record comes through per auction:

Bidder 53:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.bid_id,
  b.amount,
  b.bidder 
FROM
  auction a 
  LEFT JOIN auction_bid b 
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id 
WHERE b.bidder = 53 
  AND b.bid_id = 
  (SELECT bid_id
   FROM auction_bid 
   WHERE auction_id = b.auction_id 
   ORDER BY amount desc,bid_id desc
   LIMIT 0,1);
```

Results:

```
AUCTION_ID    AUCTION_NAME    BID_ID    AMOUNT    BIDDER
----------    ------------    ------    ------    ------
2216          Test Auction    8398      50         53
```

Bidder 32:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.bid_id,
  b.amount,
  b.bidder 
FROM
  auction a 
  LEFT JOIN auction_bid b 
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id 
WHERE b.bidder = 32 
  AND b.bid_id = 
  (SELECT bid_id
   FROM auction_bid 
   WHERE auction_id = b.auction_id 
   ORDER BY amount desc,bid_id desc
   LIMIT 0,1)
```

Zero Rows Returned: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beb2e3/6

Comment: It seems odd to me, however, that 32 didn't win this auction since 32 placed the bid first. Let me know if I have the requirement wrong and I'll update the script, or you can just change the `ORDER BY` to `amount desc,bid_id asc`.

Comment: +1 . . . This looks right to me.  I didn't realize that MySQL supported `limit` in a subquery used with `=`.  It isn't allowed for `in`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this code to the end of your query:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (select * from auction_bid tmp2 where tmp2.auction_id=b.auction_id and tmp2.amount = b.amount AND tmp2.bid_id>b.bid_id)
```

This would check to make sure that there isn't a bid of the same amount for the same auction placed after a given bid (assuming that the way you tell a later bid is a higher bid_id).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.*,
  b.bid_id,
  b.amount,
  b.bidder 
FROM
  auction a 
  LEFT JOIN auction_bid b 
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id 
WHERE b.bidder = 53 
  AND b.amount = 
  (SELECT 
    MAX(amount) 
  FROM
    auction_bid tmp 
  WHERE tmp.auction_id = b.auction_id 
  LIMIT 0, 1)
GROUP BY b.bid_id
HAVING MAX(b.bid_id)
```

You may also try this, but i can't be sure this will work without testing :

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.bid_id,
  b.amount,
  b.bidder 
FROM
  auction AS a 
  LEFT JOIN auction_bid AS b 
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id 
WHERE b.bidder = 53 
GROUP BY b.bid_id
HAVING MAX(b.amout) AND MAX(b.bid_id);
```